# pods are not running with deployment file using docker

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, virtual-machine, crashloopbackoff

thanks for trying to help me, I have a problem with me trying to run 3 replicas of a hello-world app container, what could be the resons???????
this is the error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEfqb.png)

my deployment file is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdugB.png)

and my docker file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSXzB.png)

I tried reinstalling docker, kubectl and multiple syntax versions of the deployment file

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think `WORKDIR` should be followed by `COPY`

```
...
WORKDIR /home/sigituser8
COPY requirements.txt .
...
```

and not the other way around